# C# Math.Round(). Me funciona solo una sentencia.

Tags: c#

¿Porqué la primera sentencia de redondeo me funciona y la segunda no?

```
//Esta Funciona  
decimal discountAmount = Math.Round(subTotal * discountPercent, 2);  

//Esta no funciona  
decimal discountAmount = subTotal * discountPercent;  
Math.Round(discountAmount, 2);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ambas funcionan, lo que pasa es que una la estas asignando, la otra no.

Al hacer:

```
Math.Round(...); // Donde los puntos son tu expresion aritmetica o valor.
```

No estas asignando el valor de retorno de `Math.Round(...)`, solo efectuas la operacion y no pasa mas nada luego.

Pero al hacer:

```
decimal t = Math.Round(...); // Lo mismo con los puntos...
Console.WriteLine(t); // Debe de darte el round del valor.
```

Estas asignando el resultado de la funcion `Math.Round` en la variable `t` *(En mi caso)*.

Las funciones tienen un valor de retorno, dicho valor es asignable a una variable o utilizado en una expresion, ejemplo:

```
int dos() {
    return 2; // Devuelve 2 a quien me llame.
}
```

Si hago:

```
decimal MiDecimal = Math.Round((dos() * 8.25) + 0.05, 1);
```

Eso se resume a:

```
decimal MiDecimal = Math.Round((2 * 8.25) + 0.05, 1);
```

Y efectua la operacion, siendo `16.5` el valor de `MiDecimal`.

---